# Relationship between highest eigenvalue and rank of PSD matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, order-theory, matrix-rank, positive-semidefinite

Is there any relationship between highest eigenvalue and rank of the PSD matrix? 
Let's say there are two PSD matrices $A$ and $B$ with rank $r_A$ and $r_B$ respectively and their traces are equal. Let's say that $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ are the highest eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then can we say the following?

If $ r_A \geq r_B $ then $ \lambda_A \leq \lambda_B $?

Comment: No, you can't say any of this. Just think of diagonal matrices, where the eigenvalues are just the entries on the diagonal. The rank is $n-k$, where $k$ is the number of zeros, and the highest eigenvalue is just the largest number on the diagonal.

Comment: What if $ trace (A) = trace(B) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. The rank of a PSD matrix counts the number of non-zero eigenvalues (with multiplicity).

---

The answer is still no.  Consider
$$
\pmatrix{4 \\&1\\&&1}, \qquad \pmatrix{3\\&3\\&&0}
$$

Comment: I just added a condition. What if their trace are equal?

Comment: The answer is still no

Comment: I accepted the answer but I want to discuss further. 

Consider a class of PSD matrices $ M $ such that their diagonal elements are constant $ k $ and off-diagonal elements are less than $ k$. 

If $ A,B \in M $ and $r_A \geq r_B$ then is $ \lambda_A \leq \lambda_B $?

Comment: I think that instead of asking these strange questions, you should make a post in which you explain the problem that you're really trying to solve.

Comment: As it turns out, every positive definite matrix is similar to some positive definite matrix with constant diagonal elements.  The fact that the off-diagonal elements are less than $k$ does not give you enough information about the eigenvalues.  No, it should not necessarily be the case that $r_A \geq r_B \implies \lambda_A \leq \lambda_B$.

Comment: Can you give some counter example like you gave one above? 
And I'm not trying to solve anything right now. Just curious!

Comment: @user3727929 I can't think of one off the top of my head.